# c# Social Networking Library API wrapper

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I am looking for a c# library that will allow me to post to twitter and facebook, my space etc and possibly other social networking sites.

I have found individual api wrappers such as tweetsharp but nothing that will integrate multiple social network sites.

I realize that there are different rules and requirements for each site.

Is there anything like that out there?

Thanks

Comment: Although there are different rules and requirements for each site, the underlying principles of REST based APIs are the same. It would be pretty easy to implement one yourself. It would be just a few lines of code which create headers(for post request) as per the social network and passes it to handler of each site. I have created one in python and I trust it more than the individual API wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

For Twitter, you could use the API: Twitterizer
http://www.twitterizer.net/tutorials/getting-started-with-oauth/

For Facebook,
Facebook Rest API.

Or you could use
http://www.addthis.com/personalize